# WordPress/Woocommerce custom fields displaying input value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have very little understanding of PHP but I give it a shot now and then.
Anyways, I needed to add custom fields to the "my account" page where customers can update their details. I followed a tutorial and all seemed fine until I realised that the custom fields were showing on the front-end but not under "Users" in the WordPress dashboard. I tried to find a solution and used someone elses solution and added my own fields into it.

So now the fields are showing in the dashboard like I wanted but I have PHP code in them and I have no idea why. I've edited functions.php and form-edit-account.php in the Woocommerce templates. I will paste them both below.  I've been at this for hours and before I mess it up completely, I thought I'd better try asking for help.
[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWIYz.png)
Thanks in advance

**functions.php**

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit( 'Direct script access denied.' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'AVADA_VERSION' ) ) {
    define( 'AVADA_VERSION', '7.5' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'AVADA_MIN_PHP_VER_REQUIRED' ) ) {
    define( 'AVADA_MIN_PHP_VER_REQUIRED', '5.6' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'AVADA_MIN_WP_VER_REQUIRED' ) ) {
    define( 'AVADA_MIN_WP_VER_REQUIRED', '4.9' );
}

// Developer mode.
if ( ! defined( 'AVADA_DEV_MODE' ) ) {
    define( 'AVADA_DEV_MODE', false );
}

/**
 * Compatibility check.
 *
 * Check that the site meets the minimum requirements for the theme before proceeding.
 *
 * @since 6.0
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], AVADA_MIN_WP_VER_REQUIRED, '<' ) || version_compare( PHP_VERSION, AVADA_MIN_PHP_VER_REQUIRED, '<' ) ) {
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap-compat.php';
    return;
}

/**
 * Bootstrap the theme.
 *
 * @since 6.0
 */
require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap.php';

/* Omit closing PHP tag to avoid "Headers already sent" issues. */
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode');

add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'misha_remove_my_account_links' );
function misha_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){
    
    unset( $menu_links['edit-address'] ); // Addresses
    
    
    unset( $menu_links['dashboard'] ); 
    unset( $menu_links['payment-methods'] ); 
    //unset( $menu_links['orders'] ); // Remove Orders
    unset( $menu_links['downloads'] );
    //unset( $menu_links['edit-account'] ); // Remove Account details tab
    //unset( $menu_links['customer-logout'] ); // Remove Logout link
    
    return $menu_links;
    
}


function wpc_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
if( is_user_logged_in()) { 
    if( 'sticky_navigation' == $args['theme_location'] ) { // Change top-navigation to theme specific name
        $args['menu'] = 'Player Logged-in';
    }
} else { 
    if( 'top_navigation' == $args['theme_location'] ) { // Change top-navigation to theme specific name
        $args['menu'] = 'Player Logged-out';
    }
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'wpc_wp_nav_menu_args' );

function wooc_extra_register_fields() {?>
 <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required"> *</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required"> *</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );

 /**
* register fields Validating.
*/
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
           $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Phone Number is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
       return $validation_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );

/**
* Below code save extra fields.
*/
function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
                 // Phone input filed which is used in WooCommerce
                 update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
          }
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
             //First name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
             // First name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
      }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );

add_filter('woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields', 'wc_save_account_details_required_fields' );
function wc_save_account_details_required_fields( $required_fields ){
unset( $required_fields['account_display_name'] );
return $required_fields;
}

add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'wk_custom_user_profile_fields' );

function wk_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    $casino_username = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'casino_username', true );
    $casino_password = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'casino_password', true );
    $bank = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'bank', true );
    $acc_name = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'acc_name', true );
    $acc_number = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'acc_number', true );
    $acc_type = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'acc_type', true );
  
    echo '<h3 class="heading">Custom Fields</h3>';
    
  
echo '<table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="casino_username">Casino Username</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="casino_username" id="casino_username" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->casino_username ); ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="casino_password">Casino Password</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="casino_password" id="casino_password" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->casino_password ); ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="bank">Bank</label></th>
            <td>
                <select id="bank" name="bank" size="">
                 <option value="fnb" <?php selected ( $bank, fnb ) ?>>FNB</option>
                    <option value="std" <?php selected ( $bank, std ) ?>>Standard Bank</option>
                    <option value="abs" <?php selected ( $bank, abs ) ?>>ABSA</option>
                    <option value="ned" <?php selected ( $bank, ned ) ?>>Nedbank</option>
                    <option value="cap" <?php selected ( $bank, cap ) ?>>Capitec Bank</option>
                    <option value="tym" <?php selected ( $bank, tym ) ?>>Tyme Bank</option>
                    <option value="dis" <?php selected ( $bank, dis ) ?>>Discovery Bank</option>
                    <option value="old" <?php selected ( $bank, old ) ?>>Old Mutual Bank</option>
                    <option value="afr" <?php selected ( $bank, afr ) ?>>African Bank</option>
                    <option value="mer" <?php selected ( $bank, mer ) ?>>Mercantile Bank</option>
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <th><label for="acc_name">Account Holder</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="acc_name" id="acc_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_name ); ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <th><label for="acc_number">Account Number</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="acc_number" id="acc_number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_number ); ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><label for="bank">Bank</label></th>
            <td>
                <select id="acc_type" name="acc_type" size="">
                    <option value="che" <?php selected ( $acc_type, che ) ?>>Cheque</option>
                    <option value="cur" <?php selected ( $acc_type, cur ) ?>>Current</option>
                    <option value="sav" <?php selected ( $acc_type, sav ) ?>>Savings</option>
                    <option value="inv" <?php selected ( $acc_type, inv ) ?>>Investment</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>';
    

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    /* Copy and paste this line for additional fields. Make sure to change 'u-profs' to the field ID. */
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'casino_username', $_POST['casino_username'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'casino_password', $_POST['casino_password'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'bank', $_POST['bank'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'acc_name', $_POST['acc_name'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'acc_number', $_POST['acc_number'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'acc_type', $_POST['acc_type'] );
}
}
?>
```

**form-edit-account.php**

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' ); ?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php  echo esc_attr($user_email) ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="casino_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Casino Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="casino_username" id="casino_username" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $casino_username ) ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="casino_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Casino Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="casino_password" id="casino_password" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->casino_password ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="bank"><?php _e( 'Bank', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
<select name="bank" id="bank" />
    <option disabled value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="fnb" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "fnb") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>FNB</option>
    <option value="std" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "std") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Standard Bank</option>
    <option value="abs" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "abs") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>ABSA</option>
    <option value="ned" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "ned") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Nedbank</option>
    <option value="cap" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "cap") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Capitec Bank</option>
    <option value="tym" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "tym") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Tyme Bank</option>
    <option value="dis" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "dis") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Discovery Bank</option>
    <option value="old" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "old") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Old Mutual Bank</option>
    <option value="afr" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "afr") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>African Bank</option>
    <option value="mer" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'bank', $user->ID ) == "mer") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Mercantile Bank</option>
</select>   
</p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="acc_number"><?php esc_html_e( 'Account Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="acc_number" id="acc_number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_number ); ?>" />
</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="acc_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Account Holder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="acc_name" id="acc_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="acc_type"><?php _e( 'Account Type', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
<select name="acc_type" id="acc_type" />
    <option disabled value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="che" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'acc_type', $user->ID ) == "che") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Cheque</option>
    <option value="cur" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'acc_type', $user->ID ) == "cur") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Current</option>
    <option value="sav" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'acc_type', $user->ID ) == "sav") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Savings</option>
    <option value="inv" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'acc_type', $user->ID ) == "inv") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>>Investment</option>
</select>       
</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>
```